# How to make select drop-down dependent form different database table in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I am working on projects that make administrative website to maintain the record of member or group of church.

I still learning in php and learn to use laravel framework.

Here I have 
Database Table :

1. RankPosition -> Contains Leader of FamilyMember Position, Leader of AreaMember Position
2. FamilyMember -> Contains FamilyMember name group
3. AreaMember -> Contains AreaMember name group

Now, I need to create Select drop-down in Registration page,
how to make 
when people select Leader of FamilyMember
the 2nd select drop-down popup and the list inside is taken from FamilyMember Table

and when other people select Leader of AreaMember 
the 2nd select drop-down popup and the list inside is taken from AreaMember Table

before this, I have search with keyword "dependent drop-down list" and "Country State drop-down"

But many of them just explain using 2 tables, such as category, and subcategory table

I'm just not really sure how to code normally standard/the right way to solve this issue?

I'm really thankful for every help and would greatly appreciate it.

This is the Code that I trying to do these days

For Create Page

```
{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="field">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Nama Lengkap', ['class'=>'label']) !!}
    <div class="control">
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['id'=>'name', 'class'=>"input {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'is-danger' : '' }}"]) !!}
    </div>

    @if($errors->has('name'))
        <p class="help is-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p>
    @endif
</div>

<div class="field" id="rank_group">
    {!! Form::label('rank_id', 'Jabatan', ['class'=>'label']) !!}
    <div class="control">
        <div class="select">

            {!! Form::select('rank_id', $rankData , null, array('id'=>'rank_select', 'placeholder'=>'Pilih Jabatan')) !!}

        </div>
    </div>
    @if($errors->has('family_id'))
        <p class="help is-danger">{{ $errors->has('family_id') }}</p>
    @endif
</div>


<div class="field" id="family_group">
    {!! Form::label('family_id', 'Family', ['class'=>'label']) !!}
    <div class="control">
        <div class="select">

            {!! Form::select('family_id', $familyData , null, array('id'=>'family_select', 'placeholder'=>'Pilih FA')) !!}

        </div>
    </div>
    @if($errors->has('family_id'))
        <p class="help is-danger">{{ $errors->has('family_id') }}</p>
    @endif
</div>

<div class="field" id="district_group">
    {!! Form::label('district_id', 'Rayon', ['class'=>'label']) !!}
    <div class="control">
        <div class="select">

            {!! Form::select('district_id', $districtData , null, array('id'=>'district_select', 'placeholder'=>'Pilih Rayon')) !!}

        </div>
    </div>
    @if($errors->has('family_id'))
        <p class="help is-danger">{{ $errors->has('family_id') }}</p>
    @endif
</div>

<div class="field" id="area_group">
    {!! Form::label('area_id', 'Wilayah', ['class'=>'label']) !!}
    <div class="control">
        <div class="select">

            {!! Form::select('area_id', $areaData , null, array('id'=>'area_select', 'placeholder'=>'Pilih Wilayah')) !!}

        </div>
    </div>
    @if($errors->has('family_id'))
        <p class="help is-danger">{{ $errors->has('family_id') }}</p>
    @endif
</div>


{!! Form::submit($buttonLabel, ['class'=>'button is-success is-outlined is-fullwidth m-t-50']) !!}
```

in LeaderController 
this is the create function

```
public function create()
{
    $rankData = Rank::pluck('position', 'id');
    $familyData = Family::pluck('name', 'id');
    $districtData = District::pluck('name', 'id');
    $areaData = Area::pluck('name', 'id');


    return view('leader.create', compact('familyData','districtData','areaData','rankData'));
}
```

in Script tag, I only use hide and show jquery, because I still dont have good understanding how to use AJAX get data from 3 or 4 diferent table depend on previous selection
so I came up with this code

```
$("#family_group").hide();
$("#district_group").hide();
$("#area_group").hide();


$("#rank_select").on('change', function(data){
    var id = data.target.value;

    switch(id){
        case '1':
            $("#family_group").show();
            $("#district_group").hide();
            $("#area_group").hide();    
            break;
        case '2':
            $("#family_group").hide();
            $("#district_group").show();
            $("#area_group").hide();
            break;
        case '3':
            $("#family_group").hide();
            $("#district_group").hide();
            $("#area_group").show();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried... Post your code too

Comment: You can do this using Ajax, it would be better if you provide code so that we can provide a related solution for that code.

Comment: @GYaN here I post the code, im sorry just response after a couple days, because I still trying any posibility to the code, Im very thankfull for any suggestion or correction for the code bellow , thank you

Comment: @SonuBamniya Can you give me example how to ajax this code that data taken from 3 or 4 diferent tables that responded from previous selection form..?

Comment: @GYaN Im sorry, I was wrong when posting code in the answer tag, I have clicked delete button but the answer just blocked with red, and not instantly disapear, is that normal? this is my first time using this forum by the way..